# java sql queries

Tags: java, sql, swing

I have a query. I have a database, and I am trying to write code, so that a record in the database can be created from the java software.

I have a connector class that connects to the database, then a registerStudent class, that lets the user type in value into 2 textfields. then the values should be used to create a record in the database table.

when i hit the submit button it gives me this error code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at RegisterStudent$2.actionPerformed(RegisterStudent.java:99)
```

FYI - Line 99 Code =

```
con.stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO staff (Name, Profession)"+"VALUES"+"("+"'"+name+"',"+"'"+profession+"')");
```

This is my code for the registerStudent class:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class RegisterStudent
{

    public RegisterStudent() {
        initialize();
    }

    public JFrame frmRegisterStudent;

    Connector con;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;

    // initialise the frame
    private void initialize() {
        frmRegisterStudent = new JFrame();
        frmRegisterStudent.setTitle("LEC AdminPro: RegisterStudents");
        frmRegisterStudent.setBounds(100, 100, 413, 225);
        frmRegisterStudent.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        frmRegisterStudent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        Border border = LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder();
        frmRegisterStudent.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        con = new Connector();

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 397, 189);
        frmRegisterStudent.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setBorder(border);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblRegister = new JLabel("Register Student");
        lblRegister.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblRegister.setBounds(10, 11, 124, 20);
        panel_1.add(lblRegister);

        JLabel lblSurname = new JLabel("Name");
        lblSurname.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblSurname.setBounds(10, 63, 69, 14);
        panel_1.add(lblSurname);

        JLabel lblDob = new JLabel("Profession");
        lblDob.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblDob.setBounds(10, 88, 69, 14);
        panel_1.add(lblDob);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setBounds(104, 63, 266, 20);
        panel_1.add(textField_1);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(104, 88, 266, 20);
        panel_1.add(textField_2);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
                Component form = null;
                int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(form, "Would you like to cancel the new Registration?", "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,  null, options, options);
                if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                frmRegisterStudent.setVisible(false);
            }

        }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(280, 119, 89, 23);
        panel_1.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            String name = textField_1.getText();    
            String profession = textField_1.getText();


                try {
            con.stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO staff (Name, Profession)"+"VALUES"+"("+"'"+name+"',"+"'"+profession+"')");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmRegisterStudent, "New Record has been added");

            } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Record couldn't be added!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            });



        button.setBounds(181, 119, 89, 23);
        panel_1.add(button);


    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                    try {
                RegisterStudent window = new RegisterStudent();
                window.frmRegisterStudent.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        frmRegisterStudent.setVisible(true);

}    
}
```

Comment: Probably because  `con.stmt` is null. What you have in the `Connector` class?

Comment: Does the Connector construction initialize the `stmt` field somehow?

Comment: stmt = queryConnection.createStatement();

Comment: yes it does: thats the code


    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    
       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
           Connection conn = null;

           try
           {
               String username = "root";
               String password = "";
               String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
               Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, username, password);
System.out.println ("Database connection established"); 
           }

Comment: there is a catch and exception statement too, but it wont fit in this comment. i can write it seperately if u like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the `Connector` class, which has a `stmt` field that does not get initialized.

Use this instead of the line with the NullPointerException

```
con.stmt = con.conn.prepareStatement("insert into staff (name, profession) values (?, ?)");
con.stmt.setString(1, name);
con.stmt.setString(2, profession);
con.stmt.executeUpdate();
```

But note that this is pretty bad design.

Comment: in my connector class, i got PreparedStatement stmt;

Comment: @Pita: then you have declared the field but not initialized it. Will change the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Is your connector null? I see the stmt is a field in the connector, have you initialized it?
By the way using a prepared statement is much better in your case, because it will escape the Strings (for example if they have "'" in them).

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into staff (name, profession) values (?, ?)");
pstmt.setString(1, name);
pstmt.setString(2, profession);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: yeh its null in the connector. and how do you i initialize it, and in which class? what do you mean by using a prepared statement, could you show me an example of my code with prepared statement? many thanks

Comment: This is the prepared statement sample.

Comment: thank you amir. could you also reiterate how i need to initialize the connector?

Comment: could you please explain, how i need to initialize? in my connector class, i initalized with PreparedStatement stmt;

Comment: You shall create a connection class, for example by DriverManager.createConnection(JDBC_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)

Comment: @ Amir, i have already got a connection class with it. but i just dont know what is wrong, as the error comes up.

Comment: What is your error? Have you created a prepared statement? and what is your database?

Comment: public class Connector {
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    
       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
           Connection con = null;
           
           try
           {
               String username = "root";
               String password = "";
               String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
               Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
               con = DriverManager.getConnection (url, username, password);
               System.out.println ("Database connection established");

Comment: catch (Exception e)
           {
               System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
           }        

           finally
           {
               if (con != null)
               {
                   try
                   {
                       con.close ();
                       System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
                   }
                   
                   catch (Exception e) {

Comment: Why my post is unaccepted? Isn't my code the same as the one which is accepted?

Comment: I know, but I asked you what was wrong about my code, but you didnt really identify. you just gave me a new code. but i appreciate your suggestion anyway. thanks!